No Wifi (RTL8852BE) Ubuntu 22.04 - DELL Inspiron 14
I attempted to update my (Ubuntu 22.04 / kernel 6.5 - 45) 2-in-1 Laptop (DELL Inspiron 7445) WiFi adapter (RTL8852BE) driver (HRex39 & LWFinger) a couple unsuccessful ways, but all I did was lose my WiFi adapter (WiFi option is gone from settings).
This upgrade/update was meant to resolve inconsistent WiFi and BT connectivity. Several good forum posts/guides, and drivers by a dedicated community, later and it's still nonexistent. I am appreciative of all the great drivers/info out there.
I attempted installing the drivers from HRex39 (RTL8852BE) and LWfinger (rtw89 with secure boot, MUK key added, fine). I've used make uninstall, make clean, make clean all, modprobe -r, manual file deletions and I've tried reinstalling gcc, build-essential, etc., but no go.
I found RTW-8852CE in lsmod, at some point, which is close but that's not the right version and, of course, it didn't work. So, I blacklisted it, but I still see RTW89 if I use the command ubuntu-drivers list - not sure how to remove it, but it doesn't show up in lsmod output.
Dell Inspiron 14 2-in1 (AMD 8th Gen APU 8640HS)
Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 6.5 - 45)
Realtek RTL8852BE
gcc-11 & gcc 12 (symlinked to 12)
*Secure boot enabled (but has been disabled, in the past, to test drivers)
*tried both secure boot (sign-install) and w/o.
*git, make, build-essentials, bc, etc. all (re)installed.

Attempted the -b dev branch for the driver from HRex39, but I get the same errors - which, I believe, points to an issue w/ my newer kernel. Community seems to point to just using the default Ubuntu 22.04 drivers, which do (mostly) work, and I would gladly go back to...but I don't know how!
RTW89 from LWFinger will successfully make sign-install, but is obviously not the right fit. I believe this may be what have put RTW8852CE into play, initially. Not sure.
RTL8852BE -b dev from HRex won't make, and provides the following output:
home/user/Downloads/rtl8852be/os_dep/osdep_service_linux.c: In function ‘rtw_random32’:
/home/user/Downloads/rtl8852be/os_dep/osdep_service_linux.c:850:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘prandom_u32’; did you mean ‘get_random_u32’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  850 |         return prandom_u32();
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                get_random_u32
/home/user/Downloads/rtl8852be/os_dep/osdep_service_linux.c: At top level:
/home/user/Downloads/rtl8852be/os_dep/osdep_service_linux.c:858:1: fatal error: opening dependency file /home/user/Downloads/rtl8852be/os_dep/.osdep_service_linux.o.d: Permission denied
  858 | }
      | ^

Make install looks even worse. I did get the warning that the kernel was compiled with (same version, different name, and is compiling on (same version, different name) for gcc-12, which I read should be ignored. Anything else I can provide, just let me know.
Oh, and thank you very much to everyone, in advance, for taking on the above word-wall.

Step 1: update your system firmware. Connect with an Ethernet cable and check it's fully up to date. Then, update Ubuntu. Then, go into the Software & Drivers app and check for any.
You should have done this before starting messing with 3rd party drivers, though. It may be too late now and you may need to reinstall.

Step 1: Yes, while it was still Windows (brand new system) I updated the firmware.

Step 2: Yes, of course, I updated Ubuntu via CLI and the software updater. Believe it or not, there is no Ehternet port, but I do have a USC-C to Ethernet adapter - it was just quicker to use my phone via USB-C tether.
Step 3: Yes, I'm going to backup my files to an external HDD and reload the OS from scratch. I'll have to forgo attempting better drivers for Wireless/Bluetooth.
Thank you for the helpful reply!

It's only been a short time, but think I've done everything I can at this point. I am going to backup all my files to an external drive and reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 - the default drivers work, for the most part, but bluetooth will augment/drop sound (for the worst) and WiFi reception and connectivity are weak and prone to random disconnects. Fighting with this system any longer will take far more time than a simple reload. I'll have to hope that a future update helps improve performance and stability for WiFi & bluetooth.
